# In order traversal of a trinary search tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

So, I have the following code to insert an element in a trinary search tree (left tree is less, mid is same and right tree is greater)

```
public void insert (TrinaryTree<T> root, T data) {
    //if the given tree doesn't exist yet
    if (root == null){
        root = new TrinaryTree<T>(data);
    }
    //if the given value is greater, insert to the right
    else if (root.getData().compareTo(data) > 0){
        insert (root.right, data);
    }
    //if the given value is equal, insert to the mid
    else if (root.getData().compareTo(data) == 0) {
        insert (root.mid, data);
    }
    //if the given value is less, insert to the left
    else {
        insert (root.left, data);
    }
}
```

I then try to print out my tree (in order traversal to check what I've done is correct or not using this -

```
public void inorderTraversal (TrinaryTree<T> root){
    if (root != null){
        inorderTraversal(root.getLeft());
        System.out.println(root.getData());
        inorderTraversal(root.getRight());      
    }
}
```

Now when I try to run the main class, which is this -

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    TrinaryTree<Integer> tree = new TrinaryTree<Integer>(5);
    tree.insert(tree, 4);
    tree.insert(tree, 9);
    tree.insert(tree, 5);
    tree.insert(tree, 7);
    tree.insert(tree, 2);
    tree.insert(tree, 2);       
    tree.inorderTraversal(tree);
}
```

I just get the output 5. I figured out because the main tree's left and right subtrees are null. I'm not sure as to why this is happening. My insert function works, because I put a print statement into the insert function, and the statement does get printed. Why are the subtrees still null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the code of `insert`! Once you call it with a `null` value (you want to put something to the left or right), then most likely everything is null.

- The `root.left` and `root.right` are (probably) null, and your code wont
  add the freshly created node to the node one level above.
- The value you call compareTo on is probably null (No `NPE`?)

The most important thing is, that when you call `insert` with the uninitialized value (left or right), your code will create a `TrinaryTree` node, but it wont be able to add it to it's parent (what you probably intended to do), and the freshly created node will garbage collected after the method call.